# Full table scan when doing subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty simple query on getting a player and his friends but it seems to do a full table scan and I don't see the reason for it. Do I need to rewrite this to a join to make it use the index? The player table has 7411 rows.

SQL:

```
SELECT id, credits, name, image_url FROM player WHERE ID = '999'  
or ID in(select friend_id from player_friends where player_id = '999')
```

Explain:

```
'1','PRIMARY','player','ALL','PRIMARY',NULL,NULL,NULL,'6994','Using where'
'2','DEPENDENT SUBQUERY','player_friends','ref','index2','index2','198','const,func','1','Using where; Using index'
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `player` (
`ID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Credits` decimal(12,3) DEFAULT NULL,
`Access_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Registered` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`Image_url` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `player_friends` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`player_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`friend_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index2` (`player_id`,`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: join is having better performance over subqueries

Comment: Have you tried AND instead of OR in you query?

Comment: How many rows are returned from the subselect? If there are many (does the EXPLAIN output say 198? not sure how to read it), a FTS will be faster than going through an index.

Comment: @Imran Why would they do that? That completely changes what the query means. Assuming that players can't be friends with themselves, there's no way that the ID can be both equal to their ID and the ID be in the results of the subquery.

Comment: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY is fishy. Should be independent subquery to gather all friend_ids from your index. Looks like MySQL messed up the query plan here. Try to analyze the tables/gather statistics. If that doesn't work, try writing it as a JOIN, possibly with a UNION to eliminate the OR.

Comment: Ops sorry, my mistake to understand the problem. By the way, then joining two tables is the best solution than this query.

Comment: @Thilo Seems it is a MySQL bug :-/ http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63701. I am using Google Cloud SQL on MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

First, write the query to use `exists`:

```
SELECT id, credits, name, image_url
FROM player p
WHERE ID = '999' OR
      EXISTS (select 1
              from player_friends pf
              where pf.player_id = '999' and pf.friend_id = p.id
             );
```

This may be a bit more efficient.  If it doesn't meet your needs, consider splitting it into two queries:

```
SELECT id, credits, name, image_url
FROM player p
WHERE ID = '999' 
UNION
SELECT id, credits, name, image_url
FROM player p
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
              from player_friends pf
              where pf.player_id = '999' and pf.friend_id = p.id
             );
```

Note the use of `UNION` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Hmm, I get a full table scan with the first query and the second one also says that the UNION runs a full table scan. Both SQLs also returns > 1000 rows while the user I am testing with has 3 friends :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try joining:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.credits, p1.name, p1.image_url 
FROM player p1
LEFT JOIN player_friends pf ON pf.player_id = p1.id
WHERE p1.id = '999' OR pf.friend_id = '999'
```

Comment: Still does the full table scan when I ran explain on that statement and I need to get id, credits, name and image_url of all the friends in the same query while this query will just get the main player's fields.

Comment: Fixed the condition; for the full scan, maybe you're missing a FK\index between `player` and `player_friends`

Comment: The explain says nothing in the extra column and 9330 rows and NULL for key. That doesn't sound good or? I tried added foreign keys from player_friends on both columns but it didn't make a difference for the explain statement.